# Need formula to show/bring in multiple values from col B using col A using index/match formula

Tags: excel-formula, index-match

I have Col A with the same value and Col B with diff values.  I need a formula that returns each different value in Col B using Col A as the lookup column.  Was using index/match but it only brings up the first match in this case Toy1 and ignores any and all values in Col B after the first match. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcNSk.png)

Tried index/match but only one result was returned, was hoping for an error or multiple values to return.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for someone to provide an answer. For example, let's say I asked "Have you tried [`FILTER`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)?" You might answer "Thank you!", you might answer "Dude, I need index/match like I said. Can't you read?" Or, you could say "Yes, but they doesn't work because of *insert requirement you didn't mention*." and in my experience I can't guess which response is more likely.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9h7My0n3H2LfMWA-jcQ?e=x7Rojz) / screenshot(s) refer:

**Method 1***

- assumes Office 365 compatibility (version Excel)

  =FILTER(Table1[̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿’̿’\̵͇̿̿\З= ( ▀ ͜͞ʖ▀) =Ε/̵͇̿̿/’̿’̿ ̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿],--(Table1[col A]=G4))

[image: Method 1]

[image: Method 1 - vanilla one to many]

---

**Method 2*** reverse match but can be modified for non-Office 365 users (why others don't use latest / greatest - still bewildering TBH).. anyways:

```
=LET(x_,IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table1[col A]))*MATCH(Table1[col A],G12,0),""),y_,INDEX(Table1[̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿’̿’\̵͇̿̿\З= ( ▀ ͜͞ʖ▀) =Ε/̵͇̿̿/’̿’̿ ̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿],x_),z_,FILTER(y_,ISNUMBER(x_)),z_)
```

[image: Method 2]

[image: Method 2 - reverse match (one to many)]

---

**Method 3:**

*If you've gotten this far - nothing better to do - it uses a combination of if./text join and split to be fancy schmancy:*

```
=TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",1, IF(Table1[col A]=G12,Table1[̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿’̿’\̵͇̿̿\З= ( ▀ ͜͞ʖ▀) =Ε/̵͇̿̿/’̿’̿ ̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿],"")),","))
```

[image: Method 3 - combo of various fancy shmacy functions]

---

Finally - like I didn't have anything better to do- I conclude with this wtf method - go figure yourself pls (similar to one of the above - you only asked for 1 method - so this is a bonus on bonus on yep, bonus bra)

```
=LET(x_,SORT(IF(Table1[col A]=G27,Table1[̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿’̿’\̵͇̿̿\З= ( ▀ ͜͞ʖ▀) =Ε/̵͇̿̿/’̿’̿ ̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿],""),,-1),FILTER(x_,--(x_<>"")))
```

[image: Method 4 wtf]

---

If these don't work for you (assuming 365 at the very least) - then not sure what will / although numerous ways to skin a cat.

Vote/like/subscribe as you deem fit for the benefit of future users who will invariably find themselves asking the self-same Q.
Best of luck,
ta,
J

---